# How do I fix Typescript error in imported library

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I have a Typescript error which I can't squash as it's not in my code. I'm importing a NextJs/React module called next-seo and using it as intended:

```
<NextSeo config={seoConfig} />
```

It's generating the following error:

```
JSX element type 'NextSeo' does not have any construct or call signatures
```

It does the same if I remove the config attribute so it's not that, it seems to be an error in the library itself so I have no idea how I can continue to use it without getting the author to fix it. Or am I wrong about that?

EDIT: Added some more info

Import is very simple

```
import NextSeo from 'next-seo'
```

[image]

Comment: Not enough info. Where are the type definitions coming from? TS seems to know about a type related to `NextSeo`...how? What about your import statements... what do they import?

Comment: have added as much info as I have. I didn't add more because there's nothing more to it really, just a very simple import and usage in tag, 3 lines of code is enough to cause the problem. I don't know if there is a type definition or when I might find it but VS code links to nothing as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';`

notice the curlies.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo#add-seo-to-page

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. Strange thing is that it works in my non-typescript projects as it was so I'm guessing it exports the main function as both the default export and a named export. Weird.

Comment: @jonhobbs  The type-definition in the package doesn't appear to take note of the default export that you mention, hence the problem you've been seeing: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/next-seo@4.17.0/lib/index.d.ts